# In R how to get the p-value (significance level) for selected variables rather than all variables (F-test) from a linear regression?

Tags: r, p-value

Suppose I have one outcome Y (heart disease) and I'm interested in the impact from 4 independent variables(A,B,C,D) on Y. Also I want to take into account the information of age and sex. 
So my model is:

```
model1=lm(Y~A+B+C+D+age+sex,data=MyData,na.action=na.omit)
```

I know, from F-test I can get a p-value represent the significance level of all variables in the model. But what can I do if I just want to get one p-value just represent the significance level of A,B,C,D, 4 variables from model1(I still have age and sex in model1).

Thank you very much.

Comment: `summary(lm(...whatever...))` outputs the significance of each variable.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But may I ask is there any way to eliminate the information of age and sex from F-test?

Comment: I am not clear on what you want to do but you can run `anova` to compare multiple models: `anova(fm1, fm2)` where `fm1` and `fm2` are the results of two different `lm` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, with the `mtcars` dataset. Since I do not have your data, I cannot reproduce exactly your problem.

```
# Model with many variables
mod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat, data = mtcars)

# Show p-values for variables cyl and disp only, but using the full model
summary(mod)$coefficients[c("cyl", "disp"), ]
```

So in terms of your code, try

```
summary(model1)$coefficients[c("A","B","C","D"), ]
```